# Can I reset my game in Genocide In Undertale?

Tags: undertale

I have done a pacifist run and a couple of neutral runs, but now I'm doing genocide. But I’m only in Snowdin and I feel bad. Can I reset, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to restart fresh without a genocide then follow these steps.

### Windows Users:

1. Exit Steam
2. Go to the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata*Whatever number your user ID is*\391540\remote"
3. Open "system_information_962" or "system_information_963" in "Notepad", delete everything in it, save and quit.
4. Delete "remotecache.vdf" from the "391540" folder
5. Start up Steam and Undertale. If a "Cloud Sync Conflict" window appears, you've done everything right so far.
6. While the "Cloud Sync Conflict" window is open, delete everything in the 391540 folder.
7. Click "Upload to the Steam Cloud" in the "Cloud Sync Conflict" Window. This will automatically start Undertale.
8. While Undertale is open, go into Steam right click on the Undertale application and go to "Properties".
9. Go to the "Updates" tab and uncheck "Enable Steam Cloud synchronization for Undertale".
10. Exit Undertale and Steam.
11. Delete the "391540" Folder. Now, the tainted files are removed from your steam cloud, but there's one more file to delete.
12. Open the start menu and type "Run" into the search bar and open "Run".
13. Type "%appdata%" into Run and hit enter. This open the "Roaming" folder in "Appdata"
14. Back out of "Roaming" into the Appdata folder, then open the "Local" folder.
15. Find and open the "Undertale" folder and delete "system_information_962" or "system_information_963" from that folder.
16. Open up Steam and Undertale and the game will have completely reset!

### Mac users:

1. Go to go to folder and type ~/Library/Application Support/Steam in the box
2. Userdata and you see some numbers, click on it, its different for everybody
3. Then click on 391540
4. Then click on remote
5. Then open system information 962 with TextEdit and delete everything in it
6. Delete remotecache.vdf
7. Open Steam and Undertale And if you did right you will see Steam cloud open keep steam cloud open
8. Delete Remote and remotecache.vdf
9. Click on upload to the steam cloud
10. In steam, right click Undertale click on properties Click on updates and disable steam cloud
11. Close out of steam
12. Delete 391540
13. Go to go to folder And type ~/Library/Application Support/com.tobyfox.undertale/ in the box
14. Delete system information 962 and if you see it delete system information 963
15. Enable steam cloud

Answer (score 6):

But the game is all about Genocide runs. To make you feel bad about destroying the world, and to show you that some actions have pretty heavy consequences.

There are some methods on the internet that involve [manipulating save files](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Genocide_Route#Consequence_Avoidance) or [deliberately corrupting save files](https://fucknohtml.tumblr.com/post/133037946850/do-you-own-the-steam-version-of-undertale-do-you) to fool Steam Cloud sync broken saves. It will also depend on what version you own (GOG, Steam, DRM-Free...). Reinstalling the game and disabling cloud sync(by playing offline) could be an option.

It is also a complicated topic cause that is what this game is about: Showing that not everything in life can be "undone". **That is the LESSON!**

Comment: I'd just point out that the OP has NOT finished the Genocide run yet (according to the question), so shouldn't it be as simple as resetting from the title screen in this specific case?

Comment: I thought that true reset worked, but now that I have finished a pacifist run, WOW SO CREEPY

Answer (score 3):

Since the question didn't mention actually **finishing** the genocide run you are able to reset and stop at any time. You may get a few strange bits of dialog when you reset but since you haven't completed the genocide run through to completion you are free to reset and still have the non-genocide pacific endings.

As long as you **do not complete the final cutscene** in the game you are able to reset at anytime without your game becoming corrupt from the genocide run.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to do anything to reset genocide run than patiently waiting.

Comment: Could you clarify? You can simply wait in order to reset?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answers seem to add anything that the current answers didn't.

Comment: Could be fleshed out a bit. This answer seems to deal with the case where you have actually completed genocide (beaten Sans), rebooted the game, and it now gives you a black screen with a howling wind sound, and you want to play anew, not necessarily restore to pristine state. Waiting for ~10 minutes 'restores' the game if you make a deal (although there may be some permanent *nasty surprises*, see @user65252's answer.).